# If there is a checkbox in the closest td.classname then check it

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a reservation form that lists classes, with radio buttons, for reserving a class. If the class is full, a waitlist checkbox appears on the row with the class's radio button. In jQuery, if a full class radio button is clicked, I want jQuery to check the waitlist checkbox. The td class="wailist" will be in every row, but the checkbox will only be in the HTML if the class is full.
My jQuery so far-

```
var $class_table = JQuery('table.courses');
$class_table.find('input.radio').click(function (event)
{
   //if this row has a td.waitlist with a checkbox in it then check that box
 });
```

Here is the HTML snippet:

```
<tr class="course_full">
<td class="course_select", colspan=2>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="course[1][1]"
                id="course_id_1_9"
               value="9"
                >
        Geometry 2                                              
    </label>
</td>                                       
<td class="credit_recovery"> 
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="credit_recovery[1][9]"
                id="credit_recovery_id_1_9"
                >
    </label>
</td> 
<td class="waitlist">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="waitlist[1][9]"
                    id="waitlist_id_1_9"
                    >
        </label>
</td>
```

I've failed at every 'this' 'closest' 'find' etc. Maybe length needs to be involved?

Comment: A snippet of the HTML in question or a link to the page would be helpful

Comment: It's better if you can set up a fiddle with your existing code at http://jsfiddle.net/ Then we can test there and try finding a solution for you

Comment: Didn't know about jsfiddle.net - do now! Mine is here -- http://jsfiddle.net/6VUUU/7/

Comment: @user973828 check my updated answer, seems I misunderstood how `closest` works... (so what I wrote - and you included in your fiddle - won't work) Better use explicit `parent`, `parent` and `siblings` then. (P.S. check also the capitalization - it´s `jQuery`, not `JQuery` - unless you're using an alias in your actual code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the `click` event working? If it's not, I'd suggest the [`:radio`](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/) selector:

```
$class_table.find(":radio").click(function(event) {
```

If it is, then the next step is to locate your checkbox relative to the found radio. You can simply use `parent` as @Imdad suggested (or several calls to parent) or, alternatively, [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/). Inside your callback:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.waitlist :checkbox').attr('checked', true);
```

It will locate the parent row (no matter how deeply nested your radio button is) and then search for a checkbox **inside** the column with class `waitlist`. The last call will only have any effect if the result of `find` is non-empty. Working example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/hTWwt/1/)

If you prefer to be explicit when navigating the structure, you can locate the correct column with 2 calls to `parent` and one to `siblings`, according to your HTML snippet:

```
$(this)
   .parent().parent().siblings('.waitlist')
   .find(':checkbox').attr('checked', true);
```

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/hTWwt/), should produce the same results as the first one.

(*Note:* cleaned up the answer, correct contents preserved)

Comment: The click event is working, I know this because it adds a class that highlights the row (plus I used an alert). I think your second example should be just right but the box isn't being checked. I've fiddled at http://jsfiddle.net/6VUUU/7/ but haven't gotten it. Weird. I'm sure you're right.

Comment: @user973828 I've just updated my answer (Update 2), turns out I was wrong about `closest`.

Comment: Glad it helped. On second thought, an alternative using `closest` is indeed possible: `closest("tr").find(".waitlist :checkbox")`. Check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/hTWwt/1/), should have the same results as the parent/parent/siblings

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
$class_table.find('input.radio:first-child').click(function (event)
```

to see more about :first-child visit [first-child-selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 var $class_table = JQuery('table.courses');
    $class_table.find('input.radio').click(function (event)
    {
      if($(this).parent().hasClass("waitlist"))
      {
        //DO your thing
      }
    });
```

If the radio button is not direct child of td then you may have to do .parent().parent()

You can also try `.parent().next(".waitlist") or .parent().prev(".waitlist")`

let me know if does not work